# How to check if value exists in an array from another file with xlst

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an array in a .txt like this:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3...
```

I have an xml file that has some tags containing these values like this:

```
<catalog>
    <object>
        <id> Value1 </id>
        <title> title 1 </title>
        <name> name1 </name>
    </object>
    <object>
        <id> Undesired value </id>
        <title> title 2 </title>
        <name> name2 </name>
    </object>
<catalog>
```

I want to export for example titles of this xml ONLY if their ID exists in the array of my .txt file.

Is this possible using XSLT ?

The output would be something like that:

```
<output>
    <object>
        <id> Value1 </id>
        <title> title 1 </title>
        <name> name 1 </name>
    </object>
...
</output>
```

Comment: It is possible if you use a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 or higher. Or if you know how to pass the **content** of the text file as a parameter to the transformation at runtime. However, the value `name 1` does not appear in either one of your two inputs, so that part is not possible.

Comment: I added name 1 on the XML file, it was just for the example. So which code would verify my condition ?

Comment: If your processor support XSLT 2.0, you can use the `unparsed-text()` function to read the text file, and `tokenize()` to convert it to a tree. You can then use a `key` to test if a corresponding value exists in the tree.

Comment: What have you coded so far and which version of XSLT do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following awk solution an alternative (since I simply can't think of any using XSLT).

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { print "<output>" }
NR==FNR {
  values[$0]
  next
}

/<object>/ {
  f=1
}
f { 
  i=i $0 ORS
}
/<\/object>/ {
  for (value in values)
  if(i ~ value){
    printf "%s", i
  } 
  i=f=""
}
END { print "</output>"}
```

Save the script as `tst.awk`, your list as `values.txt`, and, finally, the XML file as `input.xml`, and then run it like so:

```sh
$ awk -f tst.awk values.txt input.xml
```

It's tested with GNU Awk 5.1.0, but will work on any Unix box. If interested, I'm happy to add an explanation of the code.

Comment: "*I simply can't think of any using XSLT*" I can. In fact, it's rather trivial in XSLT 2.0 using `<xsl:copy-of select="object[id=tokenize(unparsed-text('path/to/yourfile.txt'), '&#10;')]"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are using XSLT 1.0, and the processor you use is called from the command line like `xsltproc`, you can pass the content of a text file to XSLT as a string variable.

In the example below, I will pass the content of the text file to the variable `$list` invoking `xsltproc` as follows:

```
xsltproc --stringparam list "$(cat file.txt)" transform.xsl input.xml
```

or (better):

```
xsltproc --stringparam list "$(<file.txt)" transform.xsl input.xml
```

The correspondig stylesheet `transform.xsl` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <output>
      <xsl:for-each select="object[contains($list, normalize-space (id))]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can also easily change your array into an XML file with AWK: `awk 'BEGIN{print "<array>"}{print "  <value>" $0 "</value>"}END{print "</array>"}' file.txt`.

Comment: This is not a good method to use, because a value can be contained in another value resulting in a false positive. In addition, your stylesheet needs to declare the parameter.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Let us ask to the PO if some values can be included into others.

Comment: No, this is bad practice in general.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: OK, I agree. We can't progress here as long as the PO doesn't tell us the version of XSLT he is using.

Comment: By the way, `tokenize`, which solves this problem, is sometimes available for XSLT 1.0 as an extended function (exlst).